# Finding the order of zero

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have a problem understanding how to find the order of zero of a complex function. The book is vague, and I couldnt find anything in the internet to clarify this. I have the following function
$$f(z)=z^2(1-\cos z)$$

A methodological answer would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the power series for $\cos z$? How is "order of zero" defined?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I know power series. The order of zero is defined as, if you take the derivative of a function $k$ times at the point $z_0$, it is equal to $0$. But if you now take the derivative $k+1$ times, then it is not equal to $0$.